# How to redirect url after login successful via Ajax call in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to know that how to redirect url after login successful via Ajax call in php? Kindly check my code what I am doing wrong.

Below is the registration.php file on url http://localhost:8080//myproject/adminseller/registration.php:

```
<script>
function createLogin () {
//alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

var data = {

'email'     : jQuery('#email').val(),
'password'  : jQuery('#password').val(),
 };  // data obect End

//Ajax call Start Here
jQuery.ajax({
url : '/myproject/adminseller/login.php',
method : 'POST',
data : data,
success : function(data){
//alert(data);  // For checking Code in alert

if (data != 'passed') { // passed is else statement in 
check_address.php when no errors are showing
  jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html(data);
}

if (data == 'passed') {
  //alert('passed!');

  //clear the errors if any
  jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html("");
  location.reload();
  } 
  },
  error : function (){alert("Something went wrong.");},


  });    

  }

  </script>
```

Below is the Login.php File

```
<?php

   if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
   $email = sanitize($_POST['email']);
 }

  if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
   $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);
 }

 // echo $email; // Output x2a0889@gmail.com
 // echo $password; // 123456

 // Email and password matched and no erros so I am removing validations code from here, So else condition will execute here

 // Check for Errors
    if (!empty($errors)) {
      echo display_errors($errors);
    }else{

      // Assume here login is successful
      echo 'passed';

        **// Here is the problem via Ajax Call url is not redirecting after login successful, and always getting url is: http://localhost:8080//myproject/adminseller/registration.php **
          header('Location:index.php');

    }


  ?>
```

My problem is that after successful login the url is not changing it still
http://localhost:8080//myproject/adminseller/registration.php

And I want to redirect my page http://localhost:8080//myproject/adminseller/index.php

After successful login.

Any idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Why use ajax and not just submit the form using default submit process? A server side redirect in an ajax request will not make the page change only the response to the ajax request

Comment: _Side note:_ Why are you sanitizing the password? Surly you're only saving the password hashes and not the passwords in clear text, right?

Comment: @ charlietfl , I am usings tabs Login/Signup and don't want to reload the page after every unsuccessful attempt during for validation.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, Yes I am using hash.

Comment: @ charlietfl, so there is no way to redirect the page via Ajax call? I should not use Ajax when Login Form?

Comment: Then you shouldn't sanitize the password before hashing it. That can change the password for no reason at all. If you're doing things correctly, you wouldn't need to sanitize any of the values.

Comment: @Sarah when the AJAX call hits that page, and you call `header`, you are only redirecting the ajax call and not the browser. You can do this via an AJAX call, but it needs to be done via Javascript. Check my answer for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use window.location.href not location.reload();

```
<script>
function createLogin () {
//alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

var data = {

'email'     : jQuery('#email').val(),
'password'  : jQuery('#password').val(),
 };  // data obect End

//Ajax call Start Here
jQuery.ajax({
url : '/myproject/adminseller/login.php',
method : 'POST',
data : data,
success : function(data){
//alert(data);  // For checking Code in alert

if (data != 'passed') { // passed is else statement in 
check_address.php when no errors are showing
  jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html(data);
}

if (data == 'passed') {
  //alert('passed!');

  //clear the errors if any
  jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html("");
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080//myproject/adminseller/index.php";
  } 
  },
  error : function (){alert("Something went wrong.");},


  });    

  }

  </script>
Below is the Login.php File

<?php

   if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
   $email = sanitize($_POST['email']);
 }

  if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
   $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);
 }

 // echo $email; // Output x2a0889@gmail.com
 // echo $password; // 123456

 // Email and password matched and no erros so I am removing validations code from here, So else condition will execute here

 // Check for Errors
    if (!empty($errors)) {
      echo display_errors($errors);
    }else{

      // Assume here login is successful
      echo 'passed';

        **// Here is the problem via Ajax Call url is not redirecting after login successful, and always getting url is: http://localhost:8080//myproject/adminseller/registration.php **
          header('Location:index.php');

    }


  ?>
```

Comment: @ Hamza Haider, Thanks for the reply but unfortunately not working.

Comment: does it comes in this block if (data == 'passed')  where the redirection is?

Comment: but still it is on the same page but below signin button I am getting echo value -> passed. Thats it but not redirected.

Comment: @Sarah also need to remove the redirect in login.php. Note also you can't set headers after any echo

Answer (score 0):

You are currently redirecting the AJAX request.

You cannot redirect from the PHP side on a successful AJAX request.

You can catch the returned value from Javascript however and redirect from there.

Rather than calling the header location within your PHP script, put this within the if statement checking if the response was `passd`

```
window.location.href = 'index.php';
```

This will cause the browser to go to `index.php`.

Comment: @ N.J.Dawson, Thanks for the reply but unfortunately not working.

Comment: @Sarah could you post your updated code now? I believe @Hamza's post should work if you remove `header('Location:index.php');`

Comment: @ N.J.Dawson, Mr. Hamza code is not working I also uncomment header line in php please check comment what Mr. Hamza asked me and I replied it.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting in Ajax call, which should not be the case. Please remove this line from PHP code:

> **// Here is the problem via Ajax Call url is not redirecting after login successful, and always getting url is:
>   http://localhost:8080//myproject/adminseller/registration.php **
>             header('Location:index.php');

And then replace your following JS code:n.

> //clear the errors if any   jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html("");
>   location.reload();

With Following code:

> //clear the errors if any   jQuery('#modal_errors_1').html("");
>   window.location.href = 'index.php';